# Make HelloWorld python script executable

Tags: python, macos, unix

I am trying to make a python script executable. The script is an testHelloWorld.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
print 'Hello World'
```

I have made it executable by running

```
chmod +x testHelloWorld.py
```

`$ python testHelloWorld.py` prints "Hello World". But `$ ./testHelloWorld.py` doesn't do anything.
What am I missing here?
I am using a Mac Os X device and its running Python 2.7.5.

I have gone through the answers for earlier questions and have checked for mistakes, but still no luck. This is one such similar post - [how to make python script self-executable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7562716/how-to-make-python-script-self-executable)

Comment: so no output at all and no errors?

Comment: Hmm I don't know what you're missing because i've just replicated this and it works fine. What happens if you type `which python` and `which env`. Also try `env python` and check that it opens a python interpreter for you

Comment: What happens when you replace the first line with `#!/usr/local/bin/python`?

Comment: Run `/usr/bin/env python` in bash. Does it start python or give you an error?

Comment: /usr/bin/env python is not a valid binary directory. Here you should write path to python interpreter binary file

Comment: These are the results$ which python
/usr/bin/python
$ which env
/usr/bin/env

Comment: did you ever figure this out? I'm experiencing the same problems

Answer (score 7):

On my mac:

```
#! /usr/bin/python
print 'Hello world'
```

Then

```
chmod +x <filename>.py
```

and finally

```
$ ./<filename>.py
```

gives me...

```
Hello world
```

So it is just the first line. Change to `#! /usr/bin/python`

Comment: Tried it, still no luck.
I have tried it on a MacPro and a Macbook, and got the same result.
Does anyone think it might be related to the env setup? if yes, what might be the problem.

Comment: Really??  Huh.  So you have a file called something.py and in it is exactly what I put in the first code section above. (with the /usr/bin/python).  What is the output of `which python`?

Comment: $ which python
/usr/bin/python
$ which env
/usr/bin/env

Comment: This script works fine on my linux desktop when I run it as an executable.

Comment: When you say (above) "it doesn't do anything" does it literally do nothing?  It just returns with no errors etc? Does it hang and you have to ctl-c it?  What about if you do `sudo ./<filename>.py`? (You don't want to do sudo generally.) Is it a permissions issue?  Super confused.  Have you tried this in different directories (e.g., /tmp)?  Is this an issue with that one directory?

Comment: Yes, It returns no errors.
$ sudo ./testHelloWorld.py 
Password:
$ mv testHelloWorld.py /tmp
$ /tmp/testHelloWorld.py *<No error, nothing returned>*
$ python /tmp/testHelloWorld.py 
hello world  *<expected result>*

Comment: Stumped. Wow. What is the output of `ls -asl <filename.py` (you can remove your username/group)?  How about create a bob.sh file that contains `#! /bin/sh` and `echo "Hello World", do the chmod and try `./bob.sh`. How about that?  Or create  a perl script bob.pl with `#! /usr/bin/perl` and `echo "Hello World";`, chmod and try `./bob.pl`.  Do they run?  I am running out of ideas. Haven't seen anything like this before.

Comment: ls -asl gives -> *-rwxr-xr-x  1 deepng  staff  40 Jun 19 12:25 testHelloWorld.py* The bob.sh and bob.pl file executes just fine.

Comment: Huh.  For fun, how about create a python script that writes something to a temporary file.  Something like `fp=open('/tmp/tt.txt', 'wt')` `fp.write('Test')` `fp.close()`. Run that and see if the temporary file is created.

Comment: Same result. The script just doesn't run. The tmp/ file is never created.

Comment: Did you ever get this running @deepng? I have the same results.

Answer (score 0):

Yo need to find where is located the python interpreter. Write:

```
which python
```

For me python interpreter is located at /usr/local/bin/python. So the hedaer on the python file should be that one (for me).

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python
```

After that change and making executable a python file by (chmod +x filename.py) you will be able to execute a python file by writing:

```
./filename.py
```

Answer (score -1):

On OS X, try to replace ".py" extension by ".command" ! I don't remember why but it works for me.