# Tell Flask Which Virtual Environment To Use

Tags: python, flask, virtualenv

I'm trying to setup flask on an Amazon EC2 instance.
I want to run flask with python 3.5 from an installed virtual environment.

However when I run flask it is using the ubuntu python 2.7 installation.

How do I tell flask to use the virtual environment python installation?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're running this from the CLI during development, you should already have python 3.5 on your server. If not then run `sudo apt-get install python3`. To run the app:

`python3 app.py`

However, since you are asking about `virtualenv`--which using is very good practice--you could create a new environment specifying the path of python3, as stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1534210/use-different-python-version-with-virtualenv). If you don't know the path, run `which python3`. For my computer, running Ubuntu 16.04:

`virtualenv -p /usr/bin/python3 <path/to/new/virtualenv/>`

Then:

`source <env_name>/bin/activate`

Now, this is not a very good setup even for dev and would be absolutely terrible for production. I would suggest using `uWSGI` and `NGINX` to serve your app. You can specify your `virtualenv` path in your `uWSGI` config--I would suggest using a .ini file. [Here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-flask-applications-with-uwsgi-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-16-04) is a very good Digital Ocean tutorial that I used to get started. It won't teach you everything, but it should put you on the right path. There's a lot of resources for this configuration online, so you should be able to solve any problems you run into.

Comment: Using uWSGI and Nginx allows me to specify my virtual environment path which is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

In app.py very first line add this:

```
#!/path/to/virtualenv/bin/python3.5
```

then `chmod +x app.py`

then you can run as:

```
./app.py
```

[how to make python script self-executable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7562716/how-to-make-python-script-self-executable)