# Python script with arguments from command line without typing Python

Tags: python, windows, powershell, command-line

NOT like this question: [Calling a python script from command line without typing "python" first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3400381/calling-a-python-script-from-command-line-without-typing-python-first)

I have a Python script called argparse_test.py. I put it in my system path on my Windows 10 machine so I can call it from any folder by just typing "arparse_test.py" followed by arguments.

The argument works if I call

```
python argparse_test.py -w
```

But it does not recognize arguments when I call

```
argparse_test.py -w
```

Is there a way to make this work?

Script here:

```
import argparse
import time
if __name__=='__main__':
    # Command line arguments
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("-w", "--work", action="store_true", help="Make it work")
    args = parser.parse_args()
    if args.work:
        print "It works"
    else:
        print "It doesn't work"
    time.sleep(5)
```

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to execute Python scripts in Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1934675/how-to-execute-python-scripts-in-windows) This question is about the arguments being stripped, as is yours.

Comment: @zwer I published before finished. My bad.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your issue, the presented script should work (at least it works with CPython 2.7.11).

Comment: I think the issue is permissions and some weird stuff with file associations. I'm not admin on this computer. The "possible duplicate" might have helpful answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `.py` to the `PATHEXT` environment variable. In PowerShell, do:

 `$ENV:PATHEXT += ";.py"`

Comment: Easy and accurate!

Comment: Followup, I tried the corresponding command in CMD (SET PATHEXT=%PATHEXT%;.py) but that doesn't seem to help. Any ideas there?